# ‘Means of ’ versus ‘means for’

Tags: prepositions

> Eating garlic has long been considered as a means **for** warding off malaise.
>
> Eating garlic has long been considered as a means **of** warding off malaise

Which example is preferred and why? Many thanks.

Comment: Preferred by whom? In general, neither is preferred. Take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

as a means = as a  method of doing or achieving something. Any ot the three forms would be acceptable:

Eating garlic has long been considered a means to ward off malaise.

Eating garlic has long been considered an effective means for warding off  malaise.

Eating garlic has long been considered a means of warding off malaise.

> More examples:
>
> It's an effective means for finding qualified job applicants.
>
> These pledges are a means to avoid prosecution.